# Numpy Log Calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the log returns on two time series. I have imported numpy as np and wrote the following code:

```
# Calculate the Log Returns

stocks_data_log = np.log(stocks_data / stocks_data.shift(1))
stocks_data_log.head()
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following (never ending) error message.

```
# Calculate the Log Returns

stocks_data_log = np.log(stocks_data / stocks_data.shift(1))
stocks_data_log.head()
1
# Calculate the Log Returns
2
​
3
stocks_data_log = np.log(stocks_data / stocks_data.shift(1))
4
stocks_data_log.head()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)
    148     try:
--> 149         result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
    150     except TypeError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr)
    207     if use_numexpr:
--> 208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
    209     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    120     if result is None:
--> 121         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    122 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     69     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
---> 70         return op(a, b)
     71 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-5c8fcb5cdb27> in <module>
      1 # Calculate the Log Returns
      2 
----> 3 stocks_data_log = np.log(stocks_data / stocks_data.shift(1))
      4 stocks_data_log.head()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
    701 
    702             left, right = self.align(other, join="outer", level=level, copy=False)
--> 703             new_data = left._combine_frame(right, pass_op, fill_value)
    704             return left._construct_result(new_data)
    705 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _combine_frame(self, other, func, fill_value, level)
   5298         if ops.should_series_dispatch(self, other, func):
   5299             # iterate over columns
-> 5300             new_data = ops.dispatch_to_series(self, other, _arith_op)
   5301         else:
   5302             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in dispatch_to_series(left, right, func, str_rep, axis)
    414         raise NotImplementedError(right)
    415 
--> 416     new_data = expressions.evaluate(column_op, str_rep, left, right)
    417     return new_data
    418 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr)
    206     use_numexpr = use_numexpr and _bool_arith_check(op_str, a, b)
    207     if use_numexpr:
--> 208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
    209     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    210 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    119 
    120     if result is None:
--> 121         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    122 
    123     return result

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     68         _store_test_result(False)
     69     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
---> 70         return op(a, b)
     71 
     72 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in column_op(a, b)
    383 
    384         def column_op(a, b):
--> 385             return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[:, i]) for i in range(len(a.columns))}
    386 
    387     elif isinstance(right, ABCSeries) and axis == "columns":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    383 
    384         def column_op(a, b):
--> 385             return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[:, i]) for i in range(len(a.columns))}
    386 
    387     elif isinstance(right, ABCSeries) and axis == "columns":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     62         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     63 
---> 64         return method(self, other)
     65 
     66     return new_method

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in wrapper(left, right)
    498         lvalues = extract_array(left, extract_numpy=True)
    499         rvalues = extract_array(right, extract_numpy=True)
--> 500         result = arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
    501 
    502         return _construct_result(left, result, index=left.index, name=res_name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)
    195     else:
    196         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 197             res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
    198 
    199     return res_values

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)
    149         result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
    150     except TypeError:
--> 151         result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
    152 
    153     return missing.dispatch_fill_zeros(op, left, right, result)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
     92         if mask.any():
     93             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
---> 94                 result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
     95 
     96     else:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

Here the whole script

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# Load ABB Data
ABB = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Startklar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Anaconda3 (64-bit)/ABB.csv',sep=";",names=['Datum','ABBN_Preis'])
Roche = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Startklar/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Anaconda3 (64-bit)/Roche.csv',sep=";", names=['ROG_Datum','ROG_Preis'])
Roche.head(10)

# Concatenate the different dataframes

stocks_data = pd.concat([ABB,Roche], axis=1)
stocks_data.head()

stocks_data['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(stocks_data['Datum'])
stocks_data.head()

# Kick out the Dates

stocks_data = stocks_data.loc[:,['Datum','ABBN_Preis','ROG_Preis']]
stocks_data.head()

# Compute Log Returns

stocks_data_log = np.log(stocks_data / stocks_data.shift(1))
stocks_data_log.head()
```

Comment: you get the error for trying to log a string column. is stocks_data a dataframe ? You need to specify the numeric columns to log

Comment: Post your complete script -- we're good, but we're not soothsayers.

Comment: stocks_data contains three columns, one is the date which is in datetime format. The other two columns are the time series I would like to generate the log return. How can I specify the numeric columns to log?

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, it seems you are trying to perform / operation on a string or float column. It is not clear what is stocks_data from the post.

Comment: just published the whole script, maybe then it is easier to answer the question

Comment: Is there really on one out there who can help me on that?

Comment: I don't think that log or division operations can be performed on dateTime column. I have never came across such scenario.

Comment: If you want to apply log on date, month or year then you can extract those details as new columns and then perform your calculations on that. It can be done as: stocks_data['Date']=stocks_data['Datum'].dt.day                                                                 Then select the numeric columns as:     numerical_features = stocks_data.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).copy()     OR    numerical_features = data.select_dtypes(include=['int']).copy()